# xampp control panel EAccessViolation

Tags: exception, xampp, controlpanel

Every time I quitt the xampp Control Panel following Error appears

How can I fix this?

```
  Exception EAccessViolation in module xampp-control.exe at 0025B2AE.
  Access violation at address 0065B2AE in module 'xampp-controle.exe'.
  Read of address 00000042.
```

Answer (score 19):

Before running Xampp, go to the `C:\xampp` directory, look for `xampp-control.exe`, right click on it, go to <kbd>Properties</kbd>, go to the <kbd>Compatibility</kbd> tab, and then check the <kbd>Run as administrator</kbd> option and click on <kbd>Apply</kbd>.

Comment: That solved it!

Answer (score 6):

Solution: give xampp-control.exe in C:\xampp Administration rights. See a short video on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jh1q0w-mHKU

Comment: That will work but I don't believe giving something _more_ rights that it actually needes is a wise course of action. By removing the root cause of the problem (rights on the .ini file) the problem is solved in a cleaner way. Besides having people mess with file rights might yield other unexpected problems.

Answer (score 6):

The rights on xampp-control.ini are strict by design; see [XAMPP Forum](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=82271#p277319). But *only* during install.

To solve this the easiest way is:

1. directly after install remove `c:/xampp/xampp-control.ini` (that's `.ini` not `.exe`!); the file will be created in...
2. start XAMPP Control panel, and select your preferred language.

A new `xampp-control.ini` file will be created with defaults and writable by the authenticated users and administrators. Normal users have only read access.

You won't be messing obscurely with rights, just deleting a single file. The preferred method.

Answer (score 2):

That could be a bit annoying every time you start XAMPP, I solved it by reseting permissions to d:/XAMPP/xampp-control.ini, it originally has only reading permissions, this way is a bit cleaner.

Comment: This is way more preferrable. I have no idea why they made it read only. It is just a simple configuration.